# How to vertically align div on page with flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

The following is not vertically aligning the div with text in browser tab (it is horizontally aligning correctly):

```html
<div style="height: 100%; display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center;">

  <div>
    Some vertical and horizontal aligned text
  </div>

</div>
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Set a height on the parent. In your case both `body` and `html`. When you use 100% -- think 100% of what?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The problem is with the height you given to the parent container. The `height :100%` does not take whole height. change that to `100vh` or like that

Here is the updated **[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/6q4bsfu6/1/)**

```css
.container{
  height: 100vh; 
  display: flex; 
  align-items: center; 
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    Some vertical and horizontal aligned text
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Please try bellow following code

```css
body, html{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px;
}

.demo-wp{
  height: 100%; 
  display: flex; 
  align-items: center; 
  justify-content: center;
  background:green;
}

.inner-div{
  background:gold;
  padding:20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="demo-wp">

  <div class="inner-div">
    Some vertical and horizontal aligned text
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```html
<div style="height: 100vh; display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center;">
  <div>
    Some vertical and horizontal aligned text
  </div>
</div>
```

It's because your parent `div`doesn't take the full height.

Answer (score -2):

try this

```html
<div style="height: 100%; display: -webkit-flex; display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center; background-color: lightgrey;">

  <div>
    Some vertical and horizontal aligned text
  </div>

</div>
```